# Protobuf (version3) optional field are not nullable in kotlin generated code

Tags: kotlin, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I don't understand why an optional field (like `middle_name` in the example bellow), is not nullable in the kotlin generated representation while in golang and rust is properly nullable (or optional).

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

message User{
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  optional string middle_name = 3;
  string last_name = 4;
}
```

Kotlin generated code

```java
...
public fun hasMiddleName(): kotlin.Boolean{...}
public var middleName: kotlin.String{...}
...
```

Rust generated code

```rust
...
pub middle_name: ::std::option::Option<::std::string::String>,
...
```

Golang generated code

```golang
...
MiddleName *string `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=middle_name,json=middleName,proto3,oneof" json:"middle_name,omitempty"`
...
```

The only way that I've found is using `takeIf` method on every attribute access, absolutely not error-proof (forgetting the `takeIf` check the code still works)

```java
myProto.takeIf{it.hasMiddleName()}?.middleName
```